# How to pass an Monitor object to two thread objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

When create a Ruby thread, you give a block after `Thread.new`, and after new, the thread starts execution immediately. And Ruby use `Monitor` class as mutex lock. But I don't understand how to pass a monitor object to thread execution body. See the following sample code:

```
thread1 = Thread.new do
  sum=0
  1.upto(10) {|x| sum = sum + x}
  puts("The sum of the first 10 integers is #{sum}")
end
thread2 = Thread.new do
  product=1
  1.upto(10) {|x| product = product * x}
  puts("The product of the first 10 integers is #{product}")
end
thread1.join
thread2.join
```

I want to new a `Monitor` object, and pass it to both `thread1` and `thread2` to synchronize the `puts` statement. How to do it? Please give me sample code.

This question could be asked more generally. How to pass an object to thread execution block?

Answer (score 0):

**Thread** is no different than any other classes. You can use any valid variable.

```
require 'monitor'

lock = Monitor.new

product=1
sum=0

thread1 = Thread.new do
  1.upto(10) {|x|
    sum = sum + x
    lock.synchronize do
      puts product
    end
  }
  puts("The sum of the first 10 integers is #{sum}")
end
thread2 = Thread.new do
  1.upto(10) {|x|
    product = product * x
    lock.synchronize do
      puts sum
    end
  }
  puts("The product of the first 10 integers is #{product}")
end
thread1.join
thread2.join
```

Comment: With this implementation, lock is a global variable. I'm very new to Ruby, maybe I'm still in C++ thinking. I want to pass a reference of lock to objects thread1 and thread2. Is it possible?

Comment: The key here is that is that the block passed to `Thread.new` is a *closure* —just like any other block. And @EvanLi `lock` is not a global variable, it’s a local variable in the top-level scope for this file.

Comment: Hope this makes you feel better `thread1 = Thread.new(lock) {|lock| }`