# How to create a subclass of Thread in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In C/C++, when we create a thread, there is a mechanism to pass some argument to thread execution body. In java, we can subclass the `Thread` class to allow the thread class include some instance variable. In Ruby, the way to create a thread is:

```
thread = Thread.new {
   ... code thread execution body
}
```

After `Thread.new`, the thread starts to run immediately. All code I have seen use global variables in the thread body. Say we need a mutex lock, the code is:

```
mutex = Mutex.new
thread = Thread.new {
   ... code thread execution body
   mutex.synchronized {
     ... some code
   }
}
```

Is it possible to create a subclass of `Thread` and allow it to have some instance variables? The technical issue I cannot figure out is how to pass code block to subclass and how subclass passes code block to super `Thread` class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an Monitor object to two thread objects in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435630/how-to-pass-an-monitor-object-to-two-thread-objects-in-ruby) by the same user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly, what goal are you trying to accomplish?

You don't need to subclass `Thread` in Ruby. The block of code you pass to `Thread.new` will simply be executed in the context of the code that called `Thread.new`, and will have access to the local variables of the calling method and the instance variables of the instance of the calling class.

```
class Dog
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  def start_barking
    Thread.new do
      10.times do
        puts "Woof! Woof! #{@name}!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you are looking for thread-local variables, you may use the `Thread.current` special hash.

```
10.times do |i|
  Thread.new do
    Thread.current[:i] = i
    sleep 1
    puts Thread.current[:i]
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm just trying to shift my C++ thinking to Ruby thinking. The Dog sample exactly solves my puzzle. Thanks.